# Mongoose supports BsonDocument?

Tags: mongoose

Chose MongoDB because have three clients, each has different and dynamic fields. So, I defined the schedma in C# like this:

```
int ClientID;
string ClientName;
...
BsonDocument ClientDynamicData;
```

Mongoose supports [subdoc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) but seems like must be a well-defined schema. One way to support dynamic can be

```
{
...
myDynamicDataArray: []
}
```

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found one solution, [Mixed](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed)